# How to implement a function to get the position of an element in the complex data structure?

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I've the following data structure implemented using list and dictionaries in Python.

```
data = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "6",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "7",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "8",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "9",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How to implement the following function to retrieve location of the node by id?

```
def get_location(id, data):
    pass
```

So that, this function returns me a list which I can use for referring the nodes from data, as in -

```
get_location(1, data) => [0]
get_location(2, data) => [0, 0]
get_location(3, data) => [0, 0, 0]
get_location(4, data) => [1]
get_location(5, data) => [1, 0]
get_location(6, data) => [1, 0, 0]
get_location(7, data) => [1, 0, 1]
get_location(8, data) => [1, 0, 1, 0]
get_location(9, data) => [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

This return `Tuple[int]`, not `List[int]`. But I think tuple is more fit for purpose (maybe..).
And also, *id* is `str`, not `int` because the type of *id* in data is `str`.

```py
from typing import Dict, Tuple, Any, Iterable


def get_location(id: str, data: Dict[str, Any])\
        -> Tuple[int]:
    def handler(d: Dict[str, Any], prefix: Tuple[int])\
            -> Iterable[Tuple[str, Tuple[int]]]:
        for i, item in enumerate(d):
            yield (item['id'], (*prefix, i))
            yield from handler(item['children'], (*prefix, i))
        
    // you can also initialize flatten and re-use it
    flatten = dict(handler(data, ()))
    return flatten.get(id, None)
```